# Android days left calculation wrong?

Tags: android, countdown

I am currently trying to incorporate into my app a feature where the users can enter a Date and then when they save it I want to calculate how many days are left to that date from today. My code is below:

```
public void daysLeft(String dateSent){

    String []ar = dateSent.split("[/]");
    int mDay = Integer.parseInt(ar[1]);
    int mMonth = Integer.parseInt(ar[0]);
    int mYear = Integer.parseInt(ar[2]);

    Time TimerSet = new Time();
    TimerSet.set(0, 5, 0, mDay, mMonth, mYear); //day month year
    TimerSet.normalize(true);
    long millis = TimerSet.toMillis(true);

    Time TimeNow = new Time();
    TimeNow.setToNow(); // set the date to Current Time
    TimeNow.normalize(true);
    long millis2 = TimeNow.toMillis(true);

    long millisset = millis - millis2; //subtract current from future to set the time remaining

    final int smillis = (int) (millis); //convert long to integer to display conversion results
    final int smillis2 = (int) (millis2);

    new CountDownTimer(millisset, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DateData);

            // decompose difference into days, hours, minutes and seconds 
            int weeks = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 604800);
            int days = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 86400);
            int hours = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000) - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
            int minutes = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000) 
                            - ((days * 86400) + (hours * 3600))) / 60);
            int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60);
            int millicn = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            mText.setText(" " + days);
            saveDate(String.valueOf(days));
        }

        public void onFinish() {}
    }.start();
}
```

When I run this code and say put in a date 19/07/2015 then the days remaining come back as 760 and they should have been 730. I presume there is some calculation that is slightly off and would really appreciate some help with this.

Thanks

Comment: what does millisUntilFinished  contain ? and also what is 1000 and 86400 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the month calculation. In java, Months are 0-based (0 being january).

Hence,

```
int mMonth = Integer.parseInt(ar[0]);
```

Is incorrect as in your example, it is interpreted as August.

You need to substract 1 :

```
int mMonth = Integer.parseInt(ar[0]) - 1;
```

### Edit - More details

```
TimerSet.set(0, 5, 0, mDay, mMonth, mYear);
```

takes a month that is 0-based. 7, in your example, is understood as August, which is why you need to substract 1 to the 1-based value you parsed.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the calculation and merely parses a string. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry if my explanation is not clear. See my edit for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the help im sooo hot cant think straight your 1st explanation was great :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use my `TimeSpan` class:

```
Calendar future = Calendar.getInstance();
future.set(2015, 6, 19); // month is zero based

Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.fromMiliseconds(future.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTime());

Log.d(TAG, "Days left : " + timeSpan.getDays()); // "Days left : 730"
```

`TimeSpan` class:

```
public class TimeSpan implements Comparable<TimeSpan> {
    Long days;
    Long hours;
    Long minutes;
    Long seconds;
    Long milliseconds;

    public TimeSpan() {
        days = hours = minutes = seconds = milliseconds = 0l;
    }

    public TimeSpan(long _days, long _hours, long _minutes, long _seconds, long _milliseconds) {

        long totalMS = _days * 86400000 + _hours * 3600000 + _minutes * 60000 + _seconds * 1000 + _milliseconds;

        days = Long.valueOf(totalMS / 86400000);
        totalMS -= days * 86400000;

        hours = Long.valueOf((int) totalMS / 3600000);
        totalMS -= hours * 3600000;

        minutes = Long.valueOf((int) totalMS / 60000);
        totalMS -= minutes * 60000;

        seconds = Long.valueOf((int) totalMS / 1000);
        totalMS -= seconds * 1000;

        milliseconds = Long.valueOf((int) totalMS);
    }

    public static TimeSpan fromSeconds(int _seconds) {
        return new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, _seconds, 0);
    }

    public static TimeSpan fromMiliseconds(long _miliseconds) {
        return new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, _miliseconds);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Long.toString(getTotalMilliseconds());
    }

    public String toSimpleShortString() {
        if (hours > 0)
            return String.format("%d:%d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
        else
            return String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    }

    public String toShortString() {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    }

    public String toLongString() {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
    }

    public long getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public long getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public long getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public long getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    public long getMilliseconds() {
        return milliseconds;
    }

    public long getTotalMilliseconds() {
        return days * 86400000 + hours * 3600000 + minutes * 60000 + seconds * 1000 + milliseconds;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TimeSpan another) {
        return (int) (getTotalMilliseconds() - another.getTotalMilliseconds());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried this and it returns 761 for 2 years from today's and should 730. any ideas? Thanks